HTTP 500 Internal Server Error creating subscription on Microsoft Graph API
Trying to create subscriptions to a user's mailbox for emails and calendar events. It works in most cases, but there are a few users for whom a subscription cannot be created.
Send a POST request to /users/{user_id}/calendars/{calendar_id}/events or /users/{user_id}/messages using a Microsoft Graph API v1 client. These requests for certain users result in an HTTP 500 error.
One example with a request ID:
{
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: InternalServerError; Reason: The requested resource does not exist on the server]",
    "innererror":
    {
        "client-request-id": "ef53ddb0-d55c-4b56-8f88-78cb1013b181",
        "date": "2024-10-21T00:20:07",
        "request-id": "ef53ddb0-d55c-4b56-8f88-78cb1013b181"
    }
}

There once was a subscription to this mailbox. It could not be renewed for some reason so we are trying to create a new subscription. What could cause it to fail all of a sudden?
